# How can I ignore certain strings in my string centring function?

Tags: c++, iteration, string-iteration

*N.B: Directly connected to a [problem I had a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097537/count-occurrence-of-a-set-of-characters-and-subtract-spaces-from-the-string), but I'd like to resolve the first issue there which wasn't otherwise part of the question, so please don't flag it as a duplicate of my earlier question.*

I have a [string centring function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17513466/2422013) that centres the given string according to the given width (which is 113 characters):

```
std::string center(std::string input, int width = 113) { 
    return std::string((width - input.length()) / 2, ' ') + input;
}
```

I am using a game SDK in order to create a gameserver modification, and this game SDK supports coloured strings in the game's command console, which are denoted using a dollar sign and a number from 0-9 (i.e, `$1`) and are not printed in the console itself.

The string centring function above treats these markers as part of the total string, so I want to add the total amount of characters these markers take up to the width so that the string is actually centred.

I have tried modifying the function:

```
std::string centre(std::string input, int width = 113) { 
    std::ostringstream pStream;
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
        if (i+1 > input.length()) break;
        pStream << input[i] << input[i+1];
        CryLogAlways(pStream.str().c_str());
        if (pStream.str() == "$1" || pStream.str() == "$2" || pStream.str() == "$3" || pStream.str() == "$4" || pStream.str() == "$5" || pStream.str() == "$6" || pStream.str() == "$7" || pStream.str() == "$8" || pStream.str() == "$9" || pStream.str() == "$0")
            width = width+2;
        pStream.clear();
    }
    return std::string((width - input.length()) / 2, ' ') + input;
}
```

The goal of the above function is to iterate through the string, add the current character and the next to an `ostringstream`, and evaluate the `ostringstream`.

This didn't exactly do as I wanted:

```
<16:58:57> 8I
<16:58:57> 8IIn
<16:58:57> 8IInnc
<16:58:57> 8IInncco
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoom
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommi
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiin
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiinng
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiinngg 
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiinngg  C
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiinngg  CCo
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiinngg  CCoon
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiinngg  CCoonnn
<16:58:57> 8IInnccoommiinngg  CCoonnnne
```

*(snippet from server log)*

Here's a brief summary of the issue:

[image]

I think I might be missing how iteration works; what am I missing, and how can I make this function work in the way I want it to?

Comment: I think you could display every other string as you cannot iterate two at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you are really trying to do is count the instances of `$N` in your string, where `N` is a decimal digit.  To do this, just look in the string for instances of `$` using `std::string::find`, and then check the next character to see if it is a digit.

```
std::string::size_type pos = 0;
while ((pos = input.find('$', pos)) != std::string::npos) {
    if (pos + 1 == input.size()) {
        break;  //  The last character of the string is a '$'
    }
    if (std::isdigit(input[pos + 1])) {
        width += 2;
    }
    ++pos;  //  Start next search from the next char
}
```

In order to use `std::isdigit`, you need to first:

```
#include <cctype>
```